# How to change the angle of rotation of the rotary knob? iOS

Tags: ios

I use this custom control: https://github.com/nathanday/ndrotator.
how to change the value (or angle) of rotation of the rotary knob?

thank you for the answer. The angle value between the given limits is keep! Look: i have

```
  self.fmRotator.minimumDomain = 0.5* M_PI;
  self.fmRotator.maximumDomain = 2* M_PI;

// if i set manually value instead of rotatorValue, for example:
fmRotator.angle = (0.5f*M_PI+M_PI*rotatorValue*1.5f); // it's work perfect;
//or 
rotatorValue = 5.0f/10.0f; 
fmRotator.angle = (0.5f*M_PI+M_PI*rotatorValue*1.5f); // work too.
//but
rotatorValue = mySlider.value; // UISlider, return from 0 to 1;
fmRotator.angle = (0.5f*M_PI+M_PI*rotatorValue*1.5f);
// rotatorValue is float between 0..1;
// doesn't work(
```

Comment: How does it not work? Is it going to the wrong position? Not turning? Does it crash?

Comment: Are you giving it values between 0 and 2π?

Comment: Have you inspected the value of `newAngle` to see if it's what you expect it to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/nathanday/ndrotator/blob/master/Classes/NDRotator.h) `angle` must be a value between `minimumDomain` and `maximumDomain`. The only important is to keep the `angle` value between the given limits. 
In your code if `myVariable` is less than 5.0, then nothing is going to happen. Say you use a UISlider with value range of (0 .. 1.0, the default value) and you want to rotate between -90 and +90 degrees (-PI to PI)

You may set it up like this:

```
myRotator.minimumDomain = -M_PI;
myRotator.maximumDomain = M_PI;

float newAngle = slider.value - 0.5; // translate value to -0.5 .. 0.5
myRotator.angle = newAngle * M_PI;
```

This is basic math. Just figure out what range you need and translate the slider's value to the target domain. Alternatively, you can set the minimum and maximum values of the slider to match the domain. In this case you need to add the following lines to the setup:

```
slider.minimumValue = myRotator.minimumDomain;
slider.maximumValue = myRotator.maximumDomain;
```

And the event handler will be as simple as:

```
myRotator.angle = slider.value;
[myRotator setNeedsDisplay];
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. Look: i have

Comment: I added all the details you need to implement this correctly.

Comment: [self.fmRotator setNeedsDisplay]; - solved!!!!!!

Comment: Great! I added it to the answer. I'd appreciate you accept it.